# Is there a way to determine which module corresponds to which major number?

Tags: linux, devices

In Linux, the device files in `/dev` have `major` and `minor` numbers:

```
# ll /dev
...
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,     8 Jan  5 09:02 tty8
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,     9 Jan  5 09:02 tty9
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,    64 Jan  5 09:02 ttyS0
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,    65 Jan  5 09:02 ttyS1
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,    66 Jan  5 09:02 ttyS2
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,    67 Jan  5 09:02 ttyS3
crw-------   1 root root       10,   239 Jan  5 09:02 uhid
crw-------   1 root root       10,   223 Jan  5 09:02 uinput
crw-rw-rw-   1 root root        1,     9 Jan  5 09:02 urandom
...
```

The major number corresponds to a device driver / kernel module, and I assume that I can determine which module handles each major number, by inpecting the kernel code and other documentation; but is there a command or other way to find out from the running system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can find out which majors correspond to which drivers by looking at [`/proc/devices`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html); for example

```
$ cat /proc/devices
Character devices:
  1 mem
  4 /dev/vc/0   
  4 tty
  4 ttyS
  5 /dev/tty
  5 /dev/console
  5 /dev/ptmx   
[...]
246 cec
247 hidraw
248 firewire
249 ptp
250 pps
251 bsg
252 rtc
253 dax
254 gpiochip
[...]

Block devices:  
  7 loop
  8 sd
  9 md
 11 sr
 65 sd
 66 sd
 67 sd
 68 sd
 69 sd
 70 sd
 71 sd
128 sd
129 sd
130 sd
131 sd
132 sd
133 sd
134 sd
135 sd
251 zram
252 pktcdvd
253 mdp
254 device-mapper
259 blkext
```

The advantage of this is that it shows dynamic assignments on your system, on top of [the kernel’s static assignments](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/devices.html).